# Problem with Find My

Tags: ios, find-my

I have a problem with the "Find My" feature; when I want to get my friend's location, he does not receive a notification in which he can share or reject the request.  When he sends me a message, I share it with him, I see his location, but on his phone says "no location found", everyone else can see my location and he has no problem with others either

Comment: You’ve described an issue with your friends Find My/location services; not yours.  Start your diagnostics from this angle. You also want to test against other known good devices that use Find My.

Comment: What iPhone model and what iOS version is your phone running? How about your friends' phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t really influence your friend’s phone. It seems people really want to solve things when a friend has wrong contact information or the friend’s phone doesn’t get messages or in your case, their location app isn’t able to share with you without you starting the exchange.

The best way to solve these issues is for the friend to download the Apple support app onto their phone, then to restart their phone (and do it,  not just say they did assuming it won’t help) and then work with support to fix their issues.